# php array is not showing out one variable at a time

Tags: php, email

```
foreach (array($email_with_comma) as $v) {
                mail($v,$subject_friend,$message_friend,$headers);
        }
```

$$email_with_comma contains a series of email addresses separated by comma.  example- person1@email.com, person2@email.com, person3@email.com, etc.

I tried to use loop to send email to one recipient at a time. So that the other people wont see the other contacts. 
But this code sends email to all. I am talking about only "to" option which is $v here.

Comment: You need to make it an array by `explode()` and not put it in an array a a string. `foreach( explode(",", $email_with_comma) as $v) {}`

Comment: thanks. worked. can you answer bellow so that i can mark you as approved answer?

Comment: [I have done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28427919/3000179) :) There is a 15minute wait before you can accept  as an answer though. Glad it worked out for you :)

Comment: I really hate guys putting down votes. If i knew everything i wouldnt knock here. I supposed guys were helpful here. But it seems there are so many people having rude and no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make it an array by `explode()` and not put it in an array as a string.

```
foreach( explode(",", $email_with_comma) as $v) {
    //Check for valid email 
    if (filter_var($v, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       mail($v,$subject_friend,$message_friend,$headers);
    }
}
```

Currently, you're looping around

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo@bar.com,bar@foo.com
)
```

By `explode()` on the comma (,), you'll make an array with multiple values;

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo@bar.com
    [1] => bar@foo.com
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **explode** function to split a variable then only the variable convert an array

```
$emails=explode(",", $email_with_comma);
foreach($emails as $v):
  echo $v;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Generally, the alternative syntax that you've supplied is used within HTML templating. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Nothing. I didn't downvote. However, you've supplied code but, it is my belief for something to be an actual answer, is to use the same naming and provide an answer to complete OPs aim. Within the loop you've just echo'd, and not provided the `mail`, like OP did. You're also using `explode()` on a non-existent variable (if OP were to port your answer into his/her code)